# Misunderstanding of the computation of $H_2(S^1 \times S^1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am taking the matrix point of view to work with boundary maps between the chain complexes of the standard torus. Below is a link to the cell structure I’m using which can be found on page 102 of Hatcher’s Algebraic Topology.

[Representation of the torus $S^1 \times S^1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgvK8.png)

I know that $H_2(T)= \mathbb{Z}$. Using the given cell structure, I can see that $\partial_2(U)=\partial_2(L) =a+b-c$. There are no $3$-cells, so the degree-two homology should just be

\begin{equation}
H_2(T) = \ker\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{matrix}\\ \\,\end{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\end{equation}

Here the notation $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is me being lazy to mean integer span. Therefore I’d expect the degree-two homology to be $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ which is not correct. Clearly I am not fully understanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, the two vectors you've given for the kernel are not in the chain group $C_2(T)$. (They look like they belong instead to $C_1(T)$.)

We are interested in the boundary map $d: C_2(T) \to C_1(T)$, or equivalently the map $d: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$, since there are two $2$-simplices and three $1$-simplices. The map $d$ can be represented by either a $3 \times 2$ matrix $m$ (if you're multiplying by $m$ on the left) or a $2 \times 3$ matrix $m$ (if you're multiplying by $m$ on the right. I think you're mixing up the shape of your matrix and/or the side on which you're multiplying. The kernel of the matrix should be spanned by the difference of the two $2$-simplices: it should be the span of $(1, -1)$.

Comment: Aha it seems you're right. I'm noticing that if I take the transpose of the matrix I initially wrote, and then go to take the kernel, it's spanned by (-1,1) which is what I want. This also makes more sense in the view of the chain elements themselves. I feel a little stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: No need to feel stupid, it's a very easy mistake to make.